# Reordering an SQL login statement to prevent an injection attack

Tags: sql

Here is a classic login `SELECT`statement:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{var}' AND password = md5('{var}')
```

#### Potential Attack

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'admin' -- ' AND password = md5('{var}')
```

#### My Question

Would it be still susceptible to SQL injection if I use this statement instead?

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = md5('{var}') AND username = '{var}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

Just set user name variable to `xxx' OR 1=1--` which becomes

```
...AND username = 'xxx' OR 1=1--
```

Parametrise *correctly*

Comment: how does ` OR 1=1--` works? a slight explanation would be a great help

Comment: @MattMagallo it means "give me all rows where 1=1", That is, all rows, which means "I have logged in"

Comment: would it be slowing the query process if we scan all rows using where 1=1, i mean that a lot. would it still vulnerable if we use (?) or (:variable) as variables?

Comment: The injection could be `xxx' OR username =  'admin'--` etc